# Doctype Entity Declaration rendering in HTML in browser

Tags: html, html-entities, doctype

I have the following page that I'm trying to render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [ <!ENTITY reg "&#174;"> <!ENTITY emsp "&#x2003;"> ]>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hello &reg; </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Within the DOCTYPE, I declare two html entities. However, it appears like the `]>`  at the end of that  line is rendering in the HTML. I tested this by saving the above locally in an HTML file and opening it in Chrome browser.

```
]>
hello ®
```

Why is the `]>` showing up? After reading several articles online, I believe that the DOCTYPE declaration is valid syntax.

Comment: Entity declarations seem to be for xml documents

Comment: Why are you even defining these entities? `&reg;` and `&emsp;` are built-in.

Comment: I'm using a library to convert a HTML file to PDF. It's doing some validations that requires these to be declared.

Comment: Looks like you need to be using the XML Syntax of HTML5. That doctype would be OK there. But it's not valid in the HTML syntax.